# Archangel armor flight mode – is this a bug or am I completely missing something?

Tags: steam, macos, xcom-enemy-within

I've just acquired the Archangel armor in XCOM: Enemy Within and I'm not able to ascend when in Flight Mode. I activate Flight Mode, my sniper levitates slightly off the ground, but I'm not able to find ANY way to make myself ascend levels at all like you see at the beginning of this YouTube video.

I'm not getting the movement indicator box above my soldier at all when hitting the key I've mapped to Ascend Floor. The screen shifts but no indicator box.

I'm playing using a trackpad on OS X, playing the Steam version of the game. I've tried plugging a mouse in to use the mousewheel for Ascend but no effect.

**Edit:**

I made a quick screen recording of what I'm experiencing. You can see that I'm activating Flight Mode and then both scrolling the mouse wheel (which is bound to Ascend/Descend) and using the on-screen buttons. When I've "Ascended" there's no movement indicator to show I'm flying up, but when I click around on the map you can see that the movement indicator that stays along the ground is no longer aligned to where I'm clicking.

Comment: I don't know the game, but maybe something useful here? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/127650/whats-the-point-of-the-archangel-armors-flight-capability-in-xcom

Comment: Yes, see Alex's answer to that question for the issue. I think you are activating flight mode but not actually moving vertically. The secondary problem is identifying which keys you need to press with your particular keymapping.

Comment: Nope, I'm activating flight mode and then pressing the key mapped to Ascend but nothing's happening. I've tried remapping keys, mapping the function to the mouse scroll wheel, quitting/relaunching, even reinstalling. I should note that I've played the game on the Xbox 360 before so I'm familiar with how the flight mechanic works, it just appears broken on my installation.

Comment: I've also used the clickable on-screen Ascend/Descend Floor controls to no effect.

Comment: I may be wrong, but from watching your first video it appears that the user might be clicking and holding on the unit and then ascending/descending.

Comment: @Xantec – that could very well be. I tried that as well, though, but no dice. I'm not sure which version of the game that user is playing on.

Comment: Note to editors: this question is tagged with "steam" and "os x" because if this is a bug it could very well be version-specific. Please don't remove those tags.

Comment: I recently played that game and I think those buttons are to change level, not to move the character up and down. You have to select the level (by clicking arrow up and down) and when you are at the desired level (lets say, two above the floor) then clicking (right mouse button if I'm not mistaken or maybe left double click) the level again to actually move the character to the selected place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It's a bug.** I contacted Firaxis support and it looks like this is a bug in either my install or computer setup. The exact cause is still being tracked down, but in a save file I sent to them they were able to fly using the Archangel armor with no problems. When I followed their instructions I got nothing, however.

I'm going to try installing my Steam version on another computer (or a Windows install in Boot Camp on my Mac if I can snag a Windows install disc from the office) and see what happens. Will report back if I'm able to do so!

Comment: They actually tried your save file to reproduce the issue?  That's actually some decent support for a video game.  Good luck on getting it working, Archangel armor is a very handy tool in the last half of the game.

Comment: Yeah, I've been really pleasantly surprised at the quality of support from Firaxis. I've been dealing with the same guy the entire time and he's been incredibly helpful. Haven't tracked down the issue yet so he's now put me in touch with their QA department even.